# Can't get Visual SVN server working with self-signed certificate

Tags: svn, ssl, visualsvn

I have recently upgraded to the latest VisualSVN server (on Windows) and now when I try to connect to it from my Linux svn command line client, I get this error:

```
   svn: OPTIONS of 'https://server:port/svn': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: Key usage violation in certificate has been detected.
```

I've tried downloading the PEM crt file and adding it in ~/.subversion/servers (using the ssl-authority-files) but this does not work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tekken666's suggestion did not work for me since I am on a shared environment (so I can not delete files in /usr/lib).

However, I got around my issue by simply recompiling subversion from the latest code. The problem seems to be that the svn on my hosted server was using a GNU SSL library instead of the default neon SSL library. Neon is less strict than GNU when it comes to certificate issues.

Comment: Not the best solution, actually.

Comment: Do you really mean 'Neon' or 'OpenSSL'?

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate the certificate so it will be considered valid by GnuTLS. See the VisualSVN Server KB article ["VisualSVN Server certificate key usage violation in Subversion clients built against GnuTLS"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00056/).

Answer (score -1):

-1 Uninstall the current libneon package: 
sudo apt-get remove libneon27

-2 Download the latest libneon package from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libneon27  (at the bottom you can choose the right version for your architecture).
Install the required libssl dependency:
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8

-3 Install the downloaded libneon package. E.g. for the 64Bit architecture:
dpkg -i libneon27_0.29.3-3_amd64.deb

-4 Change the symbolic links again like described above:
sudo mv /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27.old
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27

From:http://www.yeap.de/blog2.0/archives/260-Subversion-Certificate-Problems-with-Ubuntu-Precise-Pangolin.html